# Understanding the consequence of Radon-Nikodym Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

In Rudin's RCA it says the following:

> Suppose $\mu$ is a complex measure on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{M}$ in $X$. Then there is a measurable function $h$ such that $|h(x)|=1$ for all $x\in X$, and $\mathrm{d}\mu=h\mathrm{d}|\mu|$.

I don't understand the proof of this theorem. At first it says the follows:

> It is trivial that $\mu\ll|\mu|$, hence by Radon-Nikodym's Theorem we have $h\in L^1(|\mu|)$ such that $\mathrm{d}\mu=h\mathrm{d}|\mu|$.

I don't understand why Radon-Nikodym Theorem apply here. Indeed, I do know that in some references ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#For_signed_and_complex_measures), for example), Radon-Nikodym Theorem is simply referred as that $\lambda\ll\mu$ implies an $h$ such that $\mathrm{d}\lambda=h\mathrm{d}\mu$, however Rudin assert this with respect to the Lebesgue Decomposition (RCA page 121). I wonder if these two assertion is equivalent, i.e., how is Radon-Nikodym Theorem applied here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace $\lambda$ by $\mu$ and $\mu$ by $|\mu|$.

Comment: Have you ever read RCA? Rudin only says the conclusion is correct for one of the decomposition (i.e. $\lambda_a$ in RCA) but not the general case. Another book I read used Hahn's Decomposition to show this, which is a consequence in Rudin's book.

Comment: In the Theorem of Lebesgue-Radon-Nokodym one special case is when $\lambda <<\mu$. In this case, $\lambda_s=0$ (by uniqueness of the decomposition) so $\lambda_a=\lambda$ and the conclusion of the theorem becomes $\lambda (E)=\int_E hd\mu$.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is true that $\lambda_s=0$ is just the case used here.